# getting error while converting json arry

Tags: php, json, angular

from angularjs 2 my application getting below json value but i am not able to convert this json value to an array.

```
    $response = '{username: "mosh", time: "2017-01-22T11:28:54.422Z"}';
    $json_arrya = json_decode($response,true);
    var_dump($json_arrya);
```

current output: NULL
expected output as an array

Comment: quote your indexes as well

Answer (score 0):

Try the json below

```
{
    "username": "mosh",
    "time": "2017-01-22T11:28:54.422Z"
}
```

to see if that works.

Also, this is a json object not an array so you might have to pass it as an array from your angular service like

```
[{ "username": "mosh", "time": "2017-01-22T11:28:54.422Z"}]
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply, but from angularjs2 i am getting keys without double quotes

Comment: But you can try to see if its the issue on PHP end or the angular's end

Comment: I tried to check if it compiled on jsonlint but it failed! If it works with double quotes in your PHP then you will have to update your angular code to modify the json